# Annotate getter from the property

Tags: annotations, kotlin

In kotlin, we can define

```
var text: String
```

which will have a getter and a setter. It's easy to remove the setter by changing it to `val`, but what if we have a property that should only have the setter and no getter? Is there any way to create an annotation that we can apply to `text` that will deprecate the getter so others cannot use it?

The end goal is to be able to use the property syntax rather than call `setText`

Current workaround I am aware of that achieves a similar result:

```
var text: String
    @Deprecated(level = DeprecationLevel.ERROR, message = "Non readable property")
    get() = nonReadable()
    set() ...
```

I would like to know if it's possible to define something similar to

```
@SetterOnly
var text: String
    set() ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you that there is no way to complete this feature in kotlin now. since the bug [KT-3110](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-3110) is not marked as `Fixed`.

I have test the following java code in kotlin at below, it only can access setter via `setText`:

```
public class Property {
   public void setText(String text) {/**/}
   private String getText() { return "foo"; }
}
```

which means you can't remove the getter/make the getter's visibility down. so it is impossible to get rid of the `getter` like as `kotlin-allopen` plugin. so one possible solution you can do is write your own kapt plugin to throws a compile-time error, for example:

```
@SetOnly var text:String = "foo";
```

Comment: I guess I've realized that at least for now it isn't possible through directly assigning visibility, but I'm still hoping that there is a shorter way to write the annotation above. Users can still access the getter but it won't compile, which seems good enough for me.

Comment: Thank you @holi-java. I guess the plugin is the only way to go. I should also mention that I'm building for Android, so there may be better annotations than compile-time errors. If I ever accomplish it I will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want this property to be used externally, why dont you declare it as

```
private var text :String =""
```